# Erro spinner android

Tags: android, spinners

O método `setOnItemSelectedListener` não é chamado. Estou tentando obter um valor de um item por meio de um `spinner`, porém quando clico no item que desejo, nada ocorre.

Criei uma TAG pra verificar se o método está sendo chamado e não obtive nenhum resultado. Segue o código:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listColab);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerProf.setAdapter(adapter);

spinnerProf.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.i(TAG, adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView) {
        Log.i(TAG, "teste");

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que encontrei o problema, estava em meu `arrayList` composto por dados de um WebService, só não sei explicar bem o motivo pois os dados eram exibidos como esperado no meu `spinner`, ao criar um outro array e preenche-lo com dados fixos o problema não ocorreu, se descobrir o motivo do erro retornarei para complementar a resposta.